# Is there a way to round up or down a string to 5?

Tags: python

I'm building a program where it takes the final price of many items and then rounds it up or down depending on the last digit. For strings ending in 0,1,2,5,8,9 this works fine. But I need to round strings that end in 3,4,6,7 up/down to 5. How would I go about doing this?

Current code:

```
if str(finalTotalPrice).endswith(("1" , "2")) :
    roundedDown = round(finalTotalPrice, 1)
    print("Final Total = $" + str(roundedDown) + str(0))
    print()
    
    cashPayment = float( input("How much cash will you pay with? $"))
    change = (cashPayment - roundedDown)
    change = round(change, 3)
    print("Your change is $" + str(change))

elif str(finalTotalPrice).endswith(("3", "4")) :


elif str(finalTotalPrice).endswith(("6" , "7")) :
    

elif str(finalTotalPrice).endswith(("8" , "9")) :
    roundedUp = round(finalTotalPrice, 1)
    print("Final Total = $" + str(roundedUp) + str(0))
    print()

    cashPayment = float( input("How much cash will you pay with? $"))
    change = (cashPayment - roundedUp)
    change = round(change, 3)
    print("Your change is $" + str(change))

elif str(finalTotalPrice).endswith(("5" , "0")) :
    print("Final Total = $" + str(finalTotalPrice))
    print()

    cashPayment = float( input("How much cash will you pay with? $"))
    change = (cashPayment - finalTotalPrice)
    change = round(change, 3)
    print("Your change is $" + str(change))
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of input-expected output?

Comment: Note that you don't need to repeat your entire code in every if/else branch. Make a variable that holds the final value and then print that at the end of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```
def round5(n):
   return str(round(int(value) / 5.0) * 5)

value = "123"
print(round5(value)) #==> 125

value = "357"
print(round5(value)) #==> 355
```